# Схлопывание строк

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Имеется таблица с историей прохождения кейсов по разным этапам. В таблице фиксируется строка с началом этапа и его окончанием:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame([['DI00021', 'Stage1','User1','NaN','16.10.2018  2:02:15']
                   , ['DI00021','Stage1','User1','0.0264','16.10.2018  2:03:00']
                   , ['DI00021','Stage2','User2','NaN','16.10.2018  2:04:10']
                   , ['SP48576','Stage1','User3','NaN','16.10.2018 9:19:27']
                   , ['DI00021','Stage2','User2','23.9458','17.10.2018  2:00:00']
                   , ['DI00021','Stage3','User2','NaN','17.10.2018  2:00:00']
                   , ['SP48576','Stage2','User4','NaN','18.10.2018 9:26:46']
                   , ['SP48576','Stage1','User3','48.1178','18.10.2018 9:26:32']]
                  , columns=['Id','Stage', 'performer','TimeInWork','timecreated'])
```

Каким образом я могу "схлопнуть" строки?

На выходе хотелось бы получить строку с датой начала и датой окончания действия:

```
['Id','Stage', 'performer','TimeInWork','timecreatedStart', 'timecreatedEnd']
```

как пример, из первых двух строк:

```
['DI00021', 'Stage1','User1','NaN','16.10.2018  2:02:15']
                   , ['DI00021','Stage1','User1','0.0264','16.10.2018  2:03:00']
```

получить:

```
['DI00021', 'Stage1','User1','0.0264','16.10.2018  2:02:15','16.10.2018  2:03:00']
```

Comment: приведите в вопросе пример того, что вы хотите получить на выходе...

Comment: *фиксируется строка с началом этапа и его окончанием* И какие это строки? Они для каждого user, для каждого stage, для (user, stage) ?

Comment: @MaxU, добавила исправление в описание

Comment: @splash58, одна строка - это коммит для данного кейса по данной задаче. То есть когда по кейсу начинает выполняться задача, прописывается первый коммит, когда заканчивает - -второй коммит с уже заполненным полем timeinwork. Сложность в том, что по этому же кейсу позже может быть начата такая же задача, и ее нужно рассматривать отдельно - отслеживается по времени коммита и по наличии информации в timeinwork

Answer (score 4):

Сначала следует навести порядок в данных - столбцы `TimeInWork` и `timecreated` привести к правильным типам данных:

```
df["TimeInWork"] = pd.to_numeric(df["TimeInWork"], errors="coerce")
df["timecreated"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timecreated"])  

In [51]: df.dtypes
Out[51]:
Id                     object
Stage                  object
performer              object
TimeInWork            float64   #  <--- NOTE !
timecreated    datetime64[ns]   #  <--- NOTE !
dtype: object
```

Теперь можно воспользоваться группировкой и агрегацией:

```
aggs = {
  "timecreated": [("timecreatedStart", "min"),("timecreatedEnd", "max")],
  "TimeInWork": [("TimeInWork", lambda x: x.dropna().iloc[0] if len(x.dropna()) else np.nan)]
}

res = df.groupby(["Id","Stage","performer"]).agg(aggs).reset_index()
res.columns = [b or a for a,b in res.columns]
```

---

результат:

```
In [69]: res
Out[69]:
        Id   Stage performer    timecreatedStart      timecreatedEnd  TimeInWork
0  DI00021  Stage1     User1 2018-10-16 02:02:15 2018-10-16 02:03:00      0.0264
1  DI00021  Stage2     User2 2018-10-16 02:04:10 2018-10-17 02:00:00     23.9458
2  DI00021  Stage3     User2 2018-10-17 02:00:00 2018-10-17 02:00:00         NaN
3  SP48576  Stage1     User3 2018-10-16 09:19:27 2018-10-18 09:26:32     48.1178
4  SP48576  Stage2     User4 2018-10-18 09:26:46 2018-10-18 09:26:46         NaN
```

Comment: Колонка TimeInWork исчезла.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо, исправил)

Comment: Ага, вижу :) Как-то непонятнее стало)))

Answer (score 0):

А если так? https://ideone.com/lON9PX

```
columns = ['Id','Stage','performer','TimeInWork','timecreated']

data = [['DI00021', 'Stage1','User1','NaN','16.10.2018  2:02:15']
  , ['DI00021','Stage1','User1','0.0264','16.10.2018  2:03:00']
  , ['DI00021','Stage2','User2','NaN','16.10.2018  2:04:10']
  , ['SP48576','Stage1','User3','NaN','16.10.2018 9:19:27']
  , ['DI00021','Stage2','User2','23.9458','17.10.2018  2:00:00']
  , ['DI00021','Stage3','User2','NaN','17.10.2018  2:00:00']
  , ['SP48576','Stage2','User4','NaN','18.10.2018 9:26:46']
  , ['SP48576','Stage1','User3','48.1178','18.10.2018 9:26:32']]

d = {}
res1 = []
res2 = []

for row in data:
  cur = d.setdefault(row[0], {}).setdefault(row[1], [])
  if not cur:
    cur.extend(row)
    cur.append(cur[-1])
    cur[-2] = ''
    res1.append(cur)
  else:
    cur[3] = row[3]
    cur[-2] = row[-1]
    res2.append(cur)

print('=== by start ===')
print(res1)

print('=== by end ===')
print(res2)
```

Comment: Я думаю, что когда про панду спрашивают, обычно большие объёмы, так будет медленно.

Comment: @splash58, я панду не умею, да и питон в общем-то тоже. Тут за счёт словарей должна получиться линейная асимптотика, почему ты считаешь, что это будет медленно? И как можно сделать быстрее? Вот медленнее точно можно - двумя вложенными циклами, а быстрее?

Comment: @Qwertiy, модули такие как Pandas и Numpy написаны на `C` и работают в основном с данными определенного типа - т.е. когда все значения в  столбце имеют одинаковый тип данных. Векторизированные методы указанных модулей работают гораздо быстрее наивных циклов. Простой пример: `arr = np.random.rand(1000, 1000); %timeit sum(i for x in arr for i in x); %timeit arr.sum()`

Comment: @MaxU, интересная идея :)